# Cancel an existing key remap in autohotkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey, remap

I have a AutoHotKey script that asks me if I want to remap my Win keys to Ctrl or cancel their remapping, thus making them Win keys again.

However I cannot find a way to cancel the remap.  If I use the command `LWin::Lwin` I get the error message that there is a "duplicate key".

I'm new to AutoHotKey, but I did search first, so please don't bite my head off is this is a stupid question.  (It is a Lenovo laptop with Windows7-64).

Here's the script:

```
MsgBox, 4, , Remap CTRL for Desktop Keyboard?
IfMsgBox, Yes
   LWin::LCtrl
   RWin::RCtrl
   return
; Otherwise, the user picked No
;   LWin::LWin
;   RWin::RWin
;   return
```

Answer (score 1):

Various ways.

Create a hotkey to close ahk, e.g. `^!x::ExitApp` = [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[x]

Create a hotkey to disable/enable all hotkeys e.g. `f12::suspend`

Create hotkeys that ONLY work in a specific appliaction.

Here are all suggestions combined.
Under normal circumstances: `LWin::LCtrl` and `RWin::RCtrl` are active, Unless you pressed F12. You can in AHK_L set variables that can be used in `#If (Var = 1)`, where you can define Hotkeys that only work when that variable is set to 1 (true).

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; Allow the use of a portion of the wintitle
F12::
Suspend
If A_IsSuspended
    TrayTip, HotKeys, Off, 3, 0
Else
    TrayTip, HotKeys, On, 3, 0
Return

^!x::ExitApp
LWin::LCtrl
RWin::RCtrl
F1::MsgBox, Normal Mode

#IfWinActive, Window title
  F1::MsgBox, Window X is active
  F2::MsgBox, You pressed F2 inside Window x
#IfWinActive

Toggle := False
F10::Toggle := !Toggle ; Turns Mouse button ON|Off
#if Toggle ; ONLY worls in AHK_L
     LButton::Return ; Disables Mouse button
#if
```

Comment: If your script is run verbatim, it does not initialize *Toggle* - the `Toggle := False` line is never executed. That's okay in this case, since `Toggle := !Toggle` will set *Toggle* to true if it was uninitialized (empty). But it does seem to perpetuate a misunderstanding.  Also, `SetTitleMode` is invalid, your F12 hotkey shows "hotkeys on" when the hotkeys are really off and can't unsuspend since the F12 hotkey itself is suspended (as Suspend is not the hotkey's first line).

Comment: Apparently I can edit answers, so I've corrected the worst errors. Also added `\`code\`` marks.

Comment: @Lexikos, Thank you for the corrections and additions.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a version you can drive from the command line:

```
; Allow the script to be reloaded multiple times
#SingleInstance force

; Check the command line for input
NumberOfParameters = %0%

; If any command line param was passed then just unload the mappings
If ( NumberOfParameters > 0 )
{
  MsgBox Command line parameter was passed, unloading...
  ExitApp
}
Else
{
  ; Let's ask the user what they want to do
  MsgBox, 4, , Remap CTRL for Desktop Keyboard?

  IfMsgBox, Yes
  {
    ; If yes, then remap
    MsgBox Keys have been mapped.
  }
  Else
  {
    ; If no, then unload
    MsgBox Unloading mapping.
    ExitApp
  }
}

; Keys will be mapped so long as the script remains resident
LWin::LCtrl
RWin::RCtrl
```

Comment: You cannot conditionally remap a key that way.  The remappings `LWin::LCtrl` and `RWin::RCtrl` will be active immediately upon starting the script, regardless of the result of the MsgBox or even whether the MsgBox is shown at all.

Comment: I adjusted the positioning of the mappings to better reflect the true logic.  So long as the script is resident, the mappings will remain in place.